# Getting the error in Apache Spark: "No tasks have started yet"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am a beginner at Apache Spark and I'm running it in standalone mode. The task `dataframe.count()` is hanging.

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "10g");
    conf.set("spark.dirver.maxResultSize","10g");
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory ", "10g");
    //Initialize sparkcontext
    Dataframt dt = //load data from reshift
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile(url);
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRdd = rdd.mapToPair(SparkFunctionsImpl
                .strToMap());

   //dt.count()
   //pairrdd => map => collectAsMap()
```

Spark task hangs at `count()` and `collectAsMap()` and doesn't proceed from there.

[image: screenshot]

Looks like `rdd.collectAsMap` and `dataframe.count()` are executing in parallel and spark is hanging with none of the tasks proceeding.